# UIPanGestureRecognizer not working as expected with multiple pans

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

Essentially, what I want to do is to move a view around to follow the user's pan. This works fine as long as the same pan object is being used. The problem comes when the user releases and than starts another pan.

According to the documentation, the value in `translationInView` is relative to the position at the start of the pan.

So my strategy for handling this was to add two properties to my view so I can tell whether the same pan object is being used and what the reference location is. The `self` object is the object being moved. It is a UIView subclass.

```
   CGPoint originalPoint;
   if (pan == self.panObject) {
      //If the pan object is the same as the one in the property, use the saved value as the reference point.
      originalPoint = CGPointMake(self.panStartLocation.x, self.panStartLocation.y);
   } else {
      //If the pan object is DIFFERENT, set the originalPoint from the existing center.
      //self.center is in self.superview's coordinate system.
      originalPoint = CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.center.y);
      self.panStartLocation = CGPointMake(originalPoint.x, originalPoint.y);
      self.panObject = pan;
   }
   CGPoint translation = [pan translationInView:self.superview];
   self.center = CGPointMake(originalPoint.x+translation.x, originalPoint.y+translation.y);
```

This scheme doesn't work because each pan object apparently is the same object. I've spent a bit of time in the debugger verifying this, and that seems to be true. I thought the pan object would be different for each touch. So since this doesn't work, what is the alternative?

Comment: Do I need to handle this using UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan instead of checking for object changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Here is the corrected code:

```
   CGPoint originalPoint;
   if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
      originalPoint = CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.center.y);
      self.panStartLocation = CGPointMake(originalPoint.x, originalPoint.y);
   } else {
      originalPoint = CGPointMake(self.panStartLocation.x, self.panStartLocation.y);
   }
   CGPoint translation = [pan translationInView:self.superview];
   self.center = CGPointMake(originalPoint.x+translation.x, originalPoint.y+translation.y);
```

EDIT: A better approach is to take advantage of the fact that the gesture recognizer allows you to set the translation:

```
[sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) inView:self.pieceBeingMoved];
```

Do this when you move your item, and then the new translation next time will be relative to the position you just moved to.

Comment: Since posting that code I have a better solution. The pan gesture recognizer allows you to set the translation. Do this every time you move a piece, and the recognizer then does the tracking for you. I will edit my answer shortly to show this other approach.